# Open accordion when clicked in the URL

Tags: html, jquery, accordion

I have an accordion here is the code:

```
    <div class="accordion">
            <div class="accordion-title accordion-area">
              <a href="#joinus/jr-software-engineer/" id="accordion-link">Junior Software Engineer</a>
            </div>
            <div class="accordion-container">This is the Body</div>
            <div class="accordion-title accordion-area">
              <a href="#joinus/sr-software-engineer/" id="accordion-link">Senior Software Engineer</a>
            </div>
            <div class="accordion-container">This is the Body</div>
            <div class="accordion-title accordion-area">
              <a href="#joinus/software-engineer-intern/" id="accordion-link">Intern Software Engineer</a>
            </div>
            <div class="accordion-container">This is the Body</div>
    </div>
```

And the jQuery code is this to open and close the accordion

/* Accordion animation on click */

```
$(".accordion-title").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $(".accordion-title").not($(this)).removeClass("active");
    $(this).next().slideToggle("fast");
    $(".accordion-container").not($(this).next()).slideUp("fast");
  });
```

Now I want this link `#joinus/jr-software-engineer/` to be used to open the selected accordion. Like if I give `www.acc.com/#joinus/jr-software-engineer/` to someone to paste in the browser URL and if he goes to the link the accordion of the respective link will be opened automatically without clicking on the accordion itself. How can I achieve this using jQuery and with the current code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below code. Get hash url from **window.location.hash**. Using hash URL find the anchor tag with this hash URL. Added initial class to accordion container to make them display none.

```html
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
   <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".accordion-title").click(function () {
                $(this).toggleClass("active");
                $(".accordion-title").not($(this)).removeClass("active");
                $(this).next().slideToggle("fast");
                $(".accordion-container").not($(this).next()).slideUp("fast");
            });

            // get document location hash URL

            var urlHash= document.location.hash;
            if (urlHash) {
                $(".accordion-container").hide();
                var accordionLink = $("a[href='"+urlHash+"']");

                if (accordionLink && accordionLink.length > 0) {
                    accordionLink.closest('.accordion-title').trigger('click');
                }
            }

        })
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="accordion">
        <div class="accordion-title accordion-area">
            <a href="#joinus/jr-software-engineer/" id="accordion-link">Junior Software Engineer</a>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-container">This is the Body</div>
        <div class="accordion-title accordion-area">
            <a href="#joinus/sr-software-engineer/" id="accordion-link">Senior Software Engineer</a>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-container">This is the Body</div>
        <div class="accordion-title accordion-area">
            <a href="#joinus/software-engineer-intern/" id="accordion-link">Intern Software Engineer</a>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-container">This is the Body</div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Could you please explain why you added the display none css?

Comment: We need to hide the accordion container if you want to show it open on page load if URL has hash(#) present. I have updated the code. Please check.

Comment: this is working fine. Thanks a lot. You are a saviour.

Comment: could you please help me with this also? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61627453/pre-select-an-option-in-the-select-box-in-a-modal-depending-on-other-selected-va Thanks in advanced.